# c# rest client example

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

Good day!

I am new at REST api, use SOAP only (with auto-generated Visual Studio SOAP proxy client).

So, now I have a foreign system with REST-requests.

At this documentation they says that -server that handles REST requests goes to- http:///ws.

And all services addresses at- "http : //server_uri:port/WSserver/ws".

So I write simple code:

```
 string uri = "http:/localhost:8000/WSserver/ws/newsession";
  HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
        req.KeepAlive = false;
        req.ContentLength = 0;
        req.ContentType = "text/xml";

        Stream data = req.GetRequestStream();
        data.Close();
```

But I get UrlFormatxception with wrong URL-address-cannot parse Authority/Host.
So, how to use simple request to it?
Can you tell some examples?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The protocol has a typo. "http:/localhost" is missing the second '/' and should be

```
http://localhost
```

Comment: Maybe change the title related to URLFormatException so that others can search for this.

Comment: This does provide an answer, as it is the solution to the problem.